# save async with EF in foreach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

I want to save my object by iterating in a Foreach loop, and return the result to my controller

Here is the controller code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostSubmissionFirm(JArray ParamList)
{

    logger.Info(string.Format("----------  PricingController Information //// PostSubmissionFirm"));

    if (ParamList.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            string xxx1 = null;
            string xxxx2 = null;
            string xxxx3 = null;
            string xxxx4 = null;

            Cccier Ci = new Cccier (ParamList);
            List<string> verify = Ci.VerifObject();
            if (verify.Count == 0)
            {


                var Premium =  Ci.calculate();


                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created };
                return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Content = new JsonContent(new { Premium = Premium, , DateExpire = DtExp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
                };
            }
            else
            {
                HttpError err = new HttpError(message);
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, err);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And the method calculate that I call and as a result:

```
public async Task<string> calculate()
{
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var Contextli in qlimit)
    {

        Prem= Prm <= 1500 ? 1500 : Math.Round(Premium, 2);
        double Adnal1 = 100;
        double Adnal2 = Math.Round(Adnal1, 2);

        Submi SubRep = new Submi ();
        SubRep.IdSouSubmi  = 90;
        SubRep.IdPremm= i;
        SubRep.IdLi = Idl;
        SubRep.IdFran = idf;

        db.Submi.Add(SubRep);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();            
    }

    string JSONString = string.Empty;
    JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
    return JSONString;
}
```

but I get an error message right after the first iteration of the foreach loop:

Error : 500Internal Server Error{ "Message": "Une erreur s'est produite lors du démarrage d'une transaction sur la connexion du fournisseur. Pour plus d'informations, consultez l'exception interne." }

Comment: Have a look to your inner exception (exception interne). That's probably (almost 100% sure) because you're using the same DbContext for each iteration and EF's DbContext is not thread safe

Comment: I guess this is the problem. But how can i make dbcontetext thread for each iteration . And thkxxx

Comment: first of all, it is harder to get help when the error message is not in English. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
var Premium = Ci.calculate();
```

If you hadn't used `var`, you'd have seen that `Premium` is not a `string` but a `Task<string>`.

Easy fix:

```
var Premium = await Ci.calculate();
```

Note 1: nothing in that line follows c# conventions though, that should be something like

```
var premium = await Ci.CalculateAsync();
```

Note 2: `calculate` returns a JSON string and you are returning `JsonContent` so `premium` will end up being serialized twice. `calculate` should return the actual object instead.